# I can't get live() to act like hover()

Tags: javascript, jquery-events, jquery-1.4

I'm having a really big problem with live binding in jQuery 1.4. I want to bind a hover event to the div.message elements and fade in the controls. They are hidden by default. This is easy when using `.hover()`, but doesn't bind new items that are added via ajax. I've tried `.live()` with no success. It fires the `mouseover` and `mouseout` events every time the cursor moves over the various contents of the messages. As you can imagine this makes the controls flicker. I want the the controls to fade in when the mouse is over the message. But I need to bind the effect to new messages as they are loaded. I am apposed to binding hover events as messages are loaded. I would prefer a solution like live, but works exactly like hover.

```
<div id="messages">
    <div class="message">
        <div class="controls">
            <a href="dosomthing">
                do somthing
            </a>
            <a href="dosomthing">
                do somthing
            </a>
        </div>
        <p>blah blah blah</p>
    </div>
    <div class="message">
        <div class="controls">
        </div>
        <p>blah blah blah</p>
    </div>
    <div class="message">
        <div class="controls">
            <a href="dosomthing">
                do somthing
            </a>
            <a href="dosomthing">
                do somthing
            </a>
        </div>
        <p>blah blah blah</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To workaround that, you can use [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) added in version ***1.4.2*** instead like this:

```
$("#container").delegate("div", "hover", function(){
    // your code....
});
```

> .delegate()
>
> Description: Attach a handler to one
>   or more events for all elements that
>   match the selector, **now or in the
>   future**, based on a specific set of
>   root elements.

Comment: Thank you very very very much! I can go to sleep now.

Cheers, I'd buy you a beer if it was possible.